# Implication of $\dim(\ker(T)) \geq \dim(V) - \dim(W)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a $6$ dimensional subspace of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, the claim is that there exists some function $f \in V$ such that $f(\pi) = f(e) = f(6) = 0$.

I know an approach is to define a linear map $T: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ by $f \mapsto (f(\pi),f(e),f(6))$ and then because $\dim(\ker(T)) \geq \dim(V) - \dim(W)$ we have that $\dim(\ker(T)) \geq 6-3 = 3$. But at this point I want to make sure I understand the logic for the conclusion.

Is it right to say that because the kernel has dimension $3$ there are $f_1,f_2,f_3 \in V$ which are non-trivial and linearly independent for which the images of $\pi,e,6$ are all $0$? The reason being that they need to be the basis vectors for $\ker(T)$. So there isn't only a single function in $V$ for which $\pi,e,$ and $6$ are roots but there are three? Or is the conclusion that there are in fact infinitely many because we can always take the span of the three basis vectors?

Are some other approaches to this problem that maybe don't require defining such a linear transformation? Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: Hint: $0 \rightarrow ker(T) \rightarrow V \rightarrow V / ker(T) = \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence, and over a field, all exact sequences split.

Comment: @DavidLui I'm not familiar with exact sequences or splitting, and from what I've read at wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_exact_sequence I don't know if I'm at that level yet. Is there a way to convey in plain english what this means?

Comment: There is an isomorphism $V = ker(T) \oplus \mathbb{R}^3$ that commute with the obvious morphisms from $ker(T)$ and to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be very clear: With the homomorphism $T$ you defined holds
$$
f \in \ker T \iff f(\pi) = f(e) = f(6) = 0.
$$
The fact that $\dim(\ker(T)) \ge 3$ (which you proved in your question) means that the subspace $\ker(T) \subset V \subset C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is at least $3$-dimensional. Since the underlying field $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite (as a set), the vector space $\ker(T)$ also contains infinitely many elements. So yes, there are infinitely many functions $f \in V$ with $f(\pi) = f(e) = f(6) = 0$.
It is also true that you can find three such functions which are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

Notice that the statement can be derived much easier: $V$ is a vector subspace, hence contains the zero vector, which is the constant zero function. The constant zero function satisfies your condition.

Comment: I should have written explicitly that I was looking for non-trivial solutions!  Thank you this is very clear.